# how to implement QSVM for full dataset

Tags: qiskit, quantum-algorithms

I have executed the QSVM qiskit code for breast cancer dataset given [here](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stable/0.24/tutorials/machine_learning/01_qsvm_classification.html):

```
feature_dim = 2
sample_total, training_input, test_input, class_labels = breast_cancer(
    training_size=20,
    test_size=10,
    n=feature_dim,
    plot_data=True
)
```

I want to enquire whether this code works for full data set or only for a subset as given by

```
training_size=20,
test_size=10,
```

How dcan one modify this code to train on the full dataset?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it does not require any knowledge about Quantum Computing to be answered. I would recommend moving it to StackOverflow as this is a pure programming question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find your answer in the [breast_cancer source code](https://qiskit.org/documentation/machine-learning/_modules/qiskit_machine_learning/datasets/breast_cancer.html):

```
[...]
def breast_cancer(training_size, test_size, n, plot_data=False, one_hot=True):
    """returns breast cancer dataset"""
    class_labels = [r"A", r"B"]
    data, target = datasets.load_breast_cancer(return_X_y=True)
    sample_train, sample_test, label_train, label_test = train_test_split(
        data, target, test_size=0.3, random_state=12
    )
[...]
    training_input = {
        key: (sample_train[label_train == k, :])[:training_size]
        for k, key in enumerate(class_labels)
    }
    test_input = {
        key: (sample_test[label_test == k, :])[:test_size] for k, key in enumerate(class_labels)
    }
[...]
```

Three things can be denoted:

1. The `training_size` and `test_size` arguments are only used in slice objects
2. The size of the testing set is at most $30\%$ of the total size
3. There is no way to randomize the sampling since the `random_state` is hardcoded

Thus, you can do what you want by passing `None` to both `training_size` and `test_size`:

```
from qiskit_machine_learning.datasets import breast_cancer

feature_dim = 2
sample_total, training_input, test_input, class_labels = breast_cancer(
    training_size=None,
    test_size=None,
    n=feature_dim,
    plot_data=True
)
```

[image: Code result]

This gives you a training dataset with 398 samples and a test dataset with 171 samples. Now, if you want this to be randomized of if you want to have a smaller/bigger test dataset, the `breast_cancer` function can't help you, and you would have to copy-paste the aforementioned source code , remove the `random_state=12` and change the `test_size=0.3` to the desired value.

I would also recommend [opening an issue on the Qiskit GitHub](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit/issues) to ask for changing the way the code is designed, so that it allows random states and different test dataset sizes.